# Can't access tag of calling widget in server handler of a google app script

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to be able to access the tags of dynamically created widgets from a server handler function.

Here is a simple example that creates 5 checkBoxes at runtime.  I would like to access their tags in a server handler.

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var mainPanel = app.createVerticalPanel();

  var handler = app.createServerHandler('myClickHandler');

  for(var i=0; i<6; ++i) {
    var newCheckBox = app.createCheckBox()
                         .setId('cBox' +i)
                         .setName('cBox' +i)
                         .setText('checkBox ' +i)
                         .setTag('cBox' +i +' was clicked');

    newCheckBox.addValueChangeHandler(handler);

    mainPanel.add(newCheckBox);
  }

  var label = app.createLabel()
                 .setId('statusLabel')
                 .setVisible(false);

  mainPanel.add(label);

  handler.addCallbackElement(mainPanel);
  app.add(mainPanel);
  return app;
}
```

In this example, I'd like the text of the label called 'statusLabel' to be set to the tag of the checkBox that was clicked.

I know that I can read tags in a server handler if I use the name of the widget directly as in this example:

```
function myClickHandler(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  label.setText(e.parameter.cBox1_tag)
  label.setVisible(true);

  app.close();
  return app;
}
```

But what I'd like to do is to be able to pull the tag of the source with something like this

```
statusLabel.setText(e.parameter.source_tag);
```

but that fails.  I've also tried

```
var cBoxNum = e.parameter.source(e.parameter.source.length -1);
var cBoxName = 'cBox' +xBoxNum;
statusLabel.setText(e.parameter.cBoxName_tag)
```

or

```
var cBoxNum = e.parameter.source(e.parameter.source.length -1);
var cBoxName = 'cBox' +xBoxNum +'_tag';
statusLabel.setText(e.parameter.cBoxName)
```

All of those methods return 'undefined'.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a different syntax in this situation.

use brackets to get the parameter value with a "re-built" string.

like this :   `var tagValue = e.parameter[e.parameter.source+'_tag'];`

Your function as [online test here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxZCMeHknrZUzeuHtfzTqyYOz0AzT1sm8_G94Xgw-cMy7baSr8/exec)

### full code

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var mainPanel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('myClickHandler');
  for(var i=0; i<6; ++i) {
    var newCheckBox = app.createCheckBox()
            .setId('cBox' +i)
            .setName('cBox' +i)
            .setText('checkBox ' +i)
            .setTag('cBox' +i +' was clicked');
    newCheckBox.addValueChangeHandler(handler);
    mainPanel.add(newCheckBox);
  }
  var label = app.createLabel()
            .setId('statusLabel')
            .setVisible(false);
  mainPanel.add(label);
  handler.addCallbackElement(mainPanel);
  app.add(mainPanel);
  return app;
}

function myClickHandler(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var label = app.getElementById('statusLabel');
  label.setText(e.parameter[e.parameter.source+'_tag'])
  label.setVisible(true);
  return app;
}
```